# AWS Bot control on http Library

Tags: amazon-web-services, python-requests

In my project , I need to retrieve client ip address and browser info from api hit. For that my code is as follows

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.requests import Request
import httpagentparser
app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/test")
def read_root(request: Request):
    client_host = request.client.host
    browser = request.headers['user-agent'] 
   
    browser_parser = httpagentparser.simple_detect(browser)
    # 0 - Device OS, 1 - Browser (Safari, chrome )
    browser_name = browser_parser[0] + " , " + browser_parser[1]
    return {"client_host": client_host, "browser_name ": browser_name }
```

This is launched at AWS Lambda and when I make a request API , request goes throgh APIgateway with AWS Lambda as backend integration. The request is successful.

But when I enable AWS bot control , then all my requests are blocked by Bot control enabled under AWS WAF.While I look Sample of Bot categories , it is written requests blocked due to http_library.

How can I solved this problem to make my request successful after enabling AWS bot control?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize WAF behavior for your needs.
look at this - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-customize-behavior-of-aws-managed-rules-for-aws-waf/ - Case 2.

In general:

- you set the rule that block your request to COUNT (http_library rule probably) - this will add a LABEL with this rule to the request passing to next rules.
- Define another rule (with lower priority) to block all requests with this LABEL, **except** some criteria you define to mark your requests. It can be a special header you send, or your unique user-agent, or your route, any of that kind.
  This will block all requests of that rule, expect for yours.

Your whitelisting rule will look something like this (example of whitelisting a specific route for a rule:

```
{
  "Name": "whitelist-by-route",
  "Priority": 6,
  "Statement": {
    "AndStatement": {
      "Statements": [
        {
          "LabelMatchStatement": {
            "Scope": "LABEL",
            "Key": "awswaf:managed:aws:bot-control:bot:category:http_library"
          }
        },
        {
          "NotStatement": {
            "Statement": {
              "RegexMatchStatement": {
                "RegexString": "api/some_route",
                "FieldToMatch": {
                  "UriPath": {}
                },
                "TextTransformations": [
                  {
                    "Priority": 0,
                    "Type": "NONE"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "Action": {
    "Block": {}
  },
```